# Notepad++ regex not working

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, event-viewer

I am trying to use Notepad++ and regular expressions to remove all XML from Windows' events.

My regular expression is as follows:

```
Event Xml:(.|\n)+?Event>\n
```

Example Windows events are as follows:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2016/04/29 11:54:00
Event ID:      7036
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      hostname.domainname
Description:
The Adobe Flash Player Update Service service entered the stopped state.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-29T10:54:00.113587400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>299771</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="696" ThreadID="3904" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>hostname.domainname</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Adobe Flash Player Update Service</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">stopped</Data>
    <Binary>410064006F006200650046006C0061007300680050006C0061007900650072005500700064006100740065005300760063002F0031000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2016/04/29 11:54:00
Event ID:      7036
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      hostname.domainname
Description:
The Adobe Flash Player Update Service service entered the running state.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-29T10:54:00.113587400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>299770</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="696" ThreadID="3904" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>hostname.domainname</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Adobe Flash Player Update Service</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">running</Data>
    <Binary>410064006F006200650046006C0061007300680050006C0061007900650072005500700064006100740065005300760063002F0034000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

The aforementioned regular expression works in http://www.regexpal.com/:
[image]

The aforementioned regular expression does not work in Notepad++:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression `\r\nEvent Xml:(.|\r\n)+?Event>` worked exactly as desired in removing all instances regardless of trailing end-of-file newline and without enabling the option ". matches newline".

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Thanks to @DavidPostill and @Sylordis in helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 2):

#### What is the regular expressions to remove all XML?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `Event Xml:(.*?)Event>`
- Set "Replace with" to an empty string
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Enable ". matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2016/04/29 11:54:00
Event ID:      7036
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      hostname.domainname
Description:
The Adobe Flash Player Update Service service entered the stopped state.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-29T10:54:00.113587400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>299771</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="696" ThreadID="3904" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>hostname.domainname</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Adobe Flash Player Update Service</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">stopped</Data>
    <Binary>410064006F006200650046006C0061007300680050006C0061007900650072005500700064006100740065005300760063002F0031000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2016/04/29 11:54:00
Event ID:      7036
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      hostname.domainname
Description:
The Adobe Flash Player Update Service service entered the running state.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-29T10:54:00.113587400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>299770</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="696" ThreadID="3904" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>hostname.domainname</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Adobe Flash Player Update Service</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">running</Data>
    <Binary>410064006F006200650046006C0061007300680050006C0061007900650072005500700064006100740065005300760063002F0034000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**After**:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2016/04/29 11:54:00
Event ID:      7036
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      hostname.domainname
Description:
The Adobe Flash Player Update Service service entered the stopped state.


Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2016/04/29 11:54:00
Event ID:      7036
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      hostname.domainname
Description:
The Adobe Flash Player Update Service service entered the running state.
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: That's great, thank you. Any idea why mine didn't work, though?

Comment: Probably because of your <eol> characters. Windows is `\r\n`, Unix is `\n`, old Mac is `\r`. This can be a pain.

Comment: @Syslordis After some testing, it seems that you were both right. With the option ". matches newline" disabled, the regex `Event Xml:(.|\r\n)+?Event>` performed the same as the regex `Event Xml:(.*?)Event>` and the regex `Event Xml:(.|\r\n)+?Event>\r\n` only replaced the first instance due to the lack of a pre-existing end of file newline. Any ideas how to also strip out the additional newlines?

Comment: Either way it's a two step process. Add a <return> at the end of the last line and use `Event Xml:(.*?)Event>[\r\n]+` *or* use `Event Xml:(.*?)Event>` and then replace `[\r\n]+` with `\r\n`.

Comment: @mythofechelon Great. If one of the answers helped you please remember to accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check ". matches new line" option in notepad++, otherwise a regular expression should only be considered line by line.

Comment: Performing the find and replace using the above regex and that option results in ALL text being replaced.

Comment: I can't comment on David's post so I'm gonna do that here: your expression didn't work because you were searching for another line at the end of your expression, but the end of your file doesn't have a new line.

Comment: @Syslordis Surely it should have found the first instance at least?

Comment: When I tried it did actually... Just take care where your cursor here when you search and deactivate the wrap search otherwise it selected the whole file.